# tensorflow:Write failed because file could not be opened

Tags: tensorflow, keras

when i train my network,the first 100 epoch work well,but some thing wrong show:Write failed because file could not be opened,but it is still training,does it matter?

```
Epoch 243/243
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 90ms/step - loss: 4732.3154 - val_loss: 10927.1146
2019-03-22 22:26:56.227974: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:26:56.271678: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:26:56.668992: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:26:57.063331: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
Epoch 244/244
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 90ms/step - loss: 4781.3986 - val_loss: 9295.3808
2019-03-22 22:27:11.799354: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:11.846808: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:12.233436: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:12.621192: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
Epoch 245/245
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 91ms/step - loss: 4813.1783 - val_loss: 10876.4517
2019-03-22 22:27:27.450573: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:27.501519: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:27.849228: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:28.119849: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
Epoch 246/246
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 91ms/step - loss: 4679.6064 - val_loss: 10605.9655
2019-03-22 22:27:42.966834: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:43.011573: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:43.379722: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2019-03-22 22:27:43.789093: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:104] Write failed because file could not be opened.
Epoch 247/247
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 90ms/step - loss: 4745.5033 - val_loss: 10320.1687
Epoch 248/248
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 91ms/step - loss: 4839.5345 - val_loss: 9894.2434
Epoch 249/249
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 91ms/step - loss: 4963.6691 - val_loss: 10658.2467
Epoch 250/250
162/162 [==============================] - 15s 90ms/step - loss: 5010.7377 - val_loss: 9947.4776
```

Comment: "does it matter?" Well, if you don't care about TensorBoard logs, not really, no.

Answer (score 0):

As far as training is concerned it does not matter, the network will train fine. BUT, yes a big but:

- You will not be able to see any event logs
- In case you are saving the model, you will not be able to load it and reuse it.